# GWT: Disable dragging in DialogBox

Tags: gwt

Is it possible to disable dragging in a `com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.DialogBox` instance?  I like my container to have a title bar but it should be in a fixed position and the user shouldn't be capable of moving it.

If it is not possible, what's the GWT widget that fits for the job?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Extend DialogBox, override *beginDragging*, and use *preventDefault* to interrupt the drag handling.

Like so:

```
public class MyDialogBox extends DialogBox
{
   protected void beginDragging(MouseDownEvent e)
   {
      e.preventDefault();
   }
}
```

See the documentation for [DomEvent.preventDefault](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/event/dom/client/DomEvent.html#preventDefault%28%29)