# GWT Prevent DialogBox dragging

Tags: events, gwt, draggable

I need to prevent DialogBox dragging in GWT.

I have found a way to prevent the MouseDown event but nothing for dragging.

```
                            previewDialog.addDomHandler(new MouseDownHandler() {

                            @Override
                            public void onMouseDown(MouseDownEvent event) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                event.preventDefault();
                            }
                        }, MouseDownEvent.getType() );
```

How can I disable dragging on Dialog.
Any Help.??

Thanks..

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Disable Dialogbox dragging in GWT

Comment: possible duplicate of [GWT: Disable dragging in DialogBox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10659467/gwt-disable-dragging-in-dialogbox)

Answer (score 1):

Yupp:-)

I have finded out the answer..

```
final DialogBox previewDialog= new DialogBox(){;
                            protected void beginDragging(MouseDownEvent event) {
                                event.preventDefault();
                            };
                        };
```

Thanks..